# undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass, but I know the record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord

I am trying to build a simple cart based on sessions. I am using this youtube tutorial as an template: vid#4 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRVwfVUaj_Y and vid#5 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSMqi913SL4.

I am getting the same error that he gets in vid#5 at   , but he doesn't show how he fixed it.

Here are my routes:

```
get '/cart' => 'cart#index'
get '/cart/clear' => 'cart#clearCart'
get '/cart/:id' => 'cart#add'
```

And here is my cart_controller.rb:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

  def add
    id = params[:id]

    if session[:cart] then
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end

    if cart[id] then
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end

    redirect_to :action => :index
  end

  def clearCart
    session[:cart] = nil
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end

  def index


    if session[:cart] then
      @cart = session[:cart]
    else
      @cart = {}
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my cart/index.html.erb page:

```
<h3>Your Shopping Cart</h3>

<%= link_to "Empty Your Cart", cart_clear_path %>

<% total = 0 %>

<% @cart.each do | id, quantity | %>
    <% product = Product.find_by_id(id)%>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >

        <div class="product_text">
            <h3><%= product.name %></h3>
            <h3><%= product.description %></h3>
            <h3>$<%= product.price %></h3>


        </div>  
    </div>
</div>

<%end%>
```

I am very confused because I know the Product object exists, but I am still getting the error in title.

Comment: Looks like the guy didn't know what happened. And he ended up adding the "Empty your cart" link, but he already did that(empty the cart) before writing the code in the tutorial, that's why it works. What you need to do, is to remove all the code in the template, and only leave the link to Empty the cart, that way you will be able to do that, after clearing your cart, put the code back and it will work. Looks like you guys were adding products to your cart, and for some reason, one or many products do not exist, and since the values are stored in a session, you still have those products.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this dint work. Cleared code and made sure session was empty, then added code back in, but still getting same error.

Comment: Weird. For sure you must have in your session a Product that does not exist. Try printing the product id that's failing, add a line in the template that prints the product id and remove the other lines to prevent the code from crashing. You could leave an h3 and print id, and remove the rest of the lines, that way you will see the whole product list of product ids you have in you session.

Comment: If I print out all the ids of the product, they appear as "11", "13" etc., which, when checking the database, corresponds to the products. But, for some reason, I can't print out the rest of the product attributes with product = Product.find_by_id(id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help, but I found the solution. I needed to sanitize the id with .gsub('"', '') before I could pass it through to find_by_id.

This worked:

```
<% @cart.each do | id , qty | %>
<% p = Product.find_by_id(id.gsub('"', '')) %>
<%= p.name %> <%= qty %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try assigning the cart variable back to the session after you do the addition

```
def add
  id = params[:id]
  cart = session[:cart] || {}
  cart[id] = 0 unless cart[id]
  cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
  session[:cart] = cart
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

BTW I don't think if should be included in the language

```
def index
  @cart = session[:cart] || {}
end
```

### edit

The way I would have processed the Product is in the controller.  I have reservations about ever seeing the Model inside the view.  I'm not sure if this is a design pattern or not, but I would pass an array of products to the view rather than a collection of Arrays to look up.  I know for a fact this helps the test-ability of the code.

```
# app/controllers/cart_controller.rb  #should be carts_controller for RAILS convention
def index
  @cart = []
  session[:cart].each do |product_id, qty|
    @cart << {product: Product.find(product_id) , qty: qty}
  end
end
```

To use this in the view just `@cart.each do |c| <%=c.product.name %> <%=c.qty %>`

Comment: I tried assigning the cart variable again after adding to cart[id], but still didn't work. I also rearranged the code in this cleaner way. Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing the `find_by_id` with `find` so your exception will be more expressive.  I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: This is what that gives me: Couldn't find Product with 'id'="19"....but, as I said, I know Product with id 19 exists.

Comment: Is it ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception?  Do you have access to the console?  Does `Product.find(19)` return the same exception?  What does `Product.all.pluck(:id)` return?

Comment: Yes the error exception is ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CartController#index. And no, when I print out p = Product.find(19) and p.name, there is no error and the product name is displayed. When I use pluck I get the following error: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "19" does not exist.

Comment: OK, so the Error column 19 would make sense if you typed in Product.all.pluck(19) instead of pluck(:id), but the first answer p = Product.find(19) returning a valid product has me stumped!

Comment: I think it has something to do with passing in id from | id, quantity | to Product.find(id) not working.

Comment: Just tried your edit above, still get this: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CartController#index. Couldn't find Product with 'id'="19"